# ASP MVC 3 how to map fields from form to object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, serialization

**I have the next form:**

```
<form method="POST" action="test">
<input type="text" name="personFirstName" />
<input type="text" name="personLastName" />
...
</form>
```

**Also, I have next class:**

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
 public string FirstName {get;set;}
 public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

**And I have the ActionResult:**

```
public ActionResult(Person p)
{
 ...
}
```

**So how to serialize form in Person object without rename "name" in form? Is there any alias attributes? (personFirstName -> FirstName, personLastName -> LastName)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own custom model binder.

```
public class CustomModelBinder:DefaultModelBinder
{
protected override void BindProperty( ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor )
      {

      }
}
```